# how to use bq cli to force table to delete when in headless mode

Tags: google-bigquery

When running the bq command in headless mode as part of a scripted session.
I need to override the defaults on the prompt that asks if i am sure i wish to remove a table.
How can I do that?

I was trying the following command:
bq --headless --quiet rm -t id.table

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the -f flag to force deletion without confirmation

Comment: Thanks - didnt see that in the help but i guess i should have tried the obvious